# Play Framework 1.3 audit not working

Tags: playframework, hibernate-envers

I have an app that was built with Play Framework 1.2.7 and use Hibernate Envers to audit some entities (with the @Audited annotation).

Some days ago we update the app to use Play Framework 1.3.0 and everything gone great, except for one thing: @Audited stop working.

We searched over the internet for something but don't discover nothing about it. We don't change anything in the application, just migrate Play Framework to 1.3.0.

In the release notes of this version there's nothing about it.

Have anyone the same problem?

Thats my configurations (conf and deps):

dependencies.yml

```
- org.hibernate -> hibernate-envers 3.6.1.Final:
    exclude:
        - org.hibernate -> hibernate-tools 3.2.0.ga
        - org.beanshell -> bsh 2.0b4
        - freemarker -> freemarker 2.3.8
        - org.hibernate -> jtidy r8-20060801
        - ant -> ant 1.6.5
```

application.conf

```
hibernate.ejb.event.post-insert=org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PostInsertEventListener,org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener
hibernate.ejb.event.post-update=org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PostUpdateEventListener,org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener
hibernate.ejb.event.post-delete=org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PostDeleteEventListener,org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener
hibernate.ejb.event.pre-collection-update=org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener
hibernate.ejb.event.pre-collection-remove=org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener
hibernate.ejb.event.post-collection-recreate=org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please state your question more clearly in the text of the question.

Answer (score 1):

I´ve made some tests here using Hibernate Envers with Play Framework 1.3 without problems.

I believe you are having some trouble because Play Framework 1.3 uses Hibernate 4.2.15.Final, while Play Framework 1.2.7 uses 3.6.10.Final.

What about giving a try with [Hibernate Envers 4.2.20.Final](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-envers/4.2.20.Final)?

Just add the following to your dependencies.yml

```
- org.hibernate -> hibernate-envers 4.2.20.Final
```